# XCode not accepting my CLLocationCoordinate2D. Says "invalid region"

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D defaultCoordinate;
defaultCoordinate.latitude = 47.517201;
defaultCoordinate.longitude = -120.366211;
[locationView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(defaultCoordinate,   MKCoordinateSpanMake(250, 250)) animated:NO];
```

I make a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, set its coordinates, and then I simultaneously create a `MKCoordinateRegion` and set the region of my map view `locationView`.

This is the error I am getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+47.51720100, -120.36621100 span:+250.00000000, +250.00000000>'
```

Anyone know why it is giving me this error? I'm fairly sure the coordinates are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKCoordinateSpan accepts a range in degrees longitude and degrees latitude. You are passing it 250,250. The entire earths longitude only goes from -180 to 180 and latitude  from -90 to 90. You need to convert what I am assuming is a measurement of 250 meters to longitude and latitude.

Or alternatively use the function MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance

```
MKCoordinateRegion MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
   CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate,
   CLLocationDistance latitudinalMeters,
   CLLocationDistance longitudinalMeters
);
```